# How To Change the action of Context Menu key in VS Code?

Tags: contextmenu

By default, the action of the context menu key in VS Code editor is opening the context menu.
I want to change its function to run a script or execute a program for example, I tried to do that from keyboard shortcuts settings, but I didn't.

- Although I set the shortcut key (context menu) for the function that I want to perform (run a script or execute a program in terminal ...), but the context menu key function still works (when I click on the context menu key, the context menu stills appear) (https://i.stack.imgur.com/IloBV.png)
- (I want to disable the context menu from appear) - is that possible to do (Knowing that this can be done in PyCharm ...)
  [this is a picture]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uxsid.png
- Anybody can help? I'll appreciate it, Thanks.